# Rails form is not saving input to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, forms

I making a very simple RESTful app and when I input a string into the form field and submit it, the database hold NULL instead of the input string.

Here is my controller:

```
def create
  @song = Song.create(params[:title])
  flash[:success] = "You have successfully created a new project!"
  redirect_to "/songs/#{@song.id}"
end
```

Here is my form in the new.html.erb file:

```
<%= form_for(@song) do |f| %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :title %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>

<br>

<% end %>
```

Comment: I think it should be `Song.create(params[:song])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using **rails < 4** then you should have

```
def create
  @song = Song.create(params[:song])
  flash[:success] = "You have successfully created a new project!"
  redirect_to @song
end
```

and if you are using **rails > 4** then you should have

```
def create
  @song = Song.create(song_params)
  flash[:success] = "You have successfully created a new project!"
  redirect_to @song
end

private
def song_params
  params.require(:song).permit(:title)
end
```

Comment: Using `redirect_to "/songs/#{@song.id}"` is not the best way if the routes change. Better to use `redirect_to @song`

Comment: @Dear1ofGdBear If you change your routes.rb this link might stop working. It's much better to let Rails figure out the current route. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: @Iceman @Mandeep I am getting an error... 'undefined method `song_url' for #<SongsController:0x007fc0ae1c53b0>'  It points the the newly edited line of 'redirect_to @song'

Comment: @Dear1ofGdBear that is a separate question and make sure you put your routes.rb file in your question :)

Comment: What does your routes.rb look like? You will need a line `resources :songs` for this to work

Comment: @Iceman @Mandeep I added `resources :songs` in the routes.rb file an it works now.